# Pytorch broadcasting product of two tensors

Tags: python, deep-learning, matrix-multiplication, pytorch, tensor

I want to multiply two tensors, here is what I have got:

- `A` tensor of shape `(20, 96, 110)`
- `B` tensor of shape `(20, 16, 110)`

The first index is for batch size.
What I want to do is essentially take each tensor from `B` - `(20, 1, 110)`, for example, and with that, I want to multiply each `A` tensor `(20, n, 110)`.
So the product will be at the end: tensor `AB` which shape is `(20, 96 * 16, 110)`.

So I want to multiply each tensor from `A` by broadcasting with `B`.
Is there a method in PyTorch that does it?

Comment: Im not sure, but from what i can gather because you want to multiply the first element of tensor a to the first element of tensor b,The product will be always the same for all the 20 batches, So why dont you just plainly initialize a tensor of `torch.tensor(20, 96*16, 110)` here 20 being the batch size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.einsum) followed by [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.reshape):

```
AB = torch.einsum("ijk,ilk->ijlk", (A, B)).reshape(A.shape[0], -1, A.shape[2])
```

---

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

# A of shape (2, 3, 2):
A = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], 
                               [[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]]]))
# B of shape (2, 2, 2):
B = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[[1, 1], [10, 10]], 
                               [[2, 2], [20, 20]]]))

# AB of shape (2, 3*2, 2):
AB = torch.einsum("ijk,ilk->ijlk", (A, B)).reshape(A.shape[0], -1, A.shape[2])
# tensor([[[ 1, 1], [ 10, 10], [  2,  2], [ 20,   20], [ 3,   3], [ 30,  30]],
#         [[ 8, 8], [ 80, 80], [ 10, 10], [ 100, 100], [ 12, 12], [ 120, 120]]])
```

Comment: @ Aldream Nice.